# subtract two column in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My source data looks like this screenshot 
[image: Source Data]

I would like to know

1. How many purchase order numbers (column `po no`) has each project?
2. How many `po no` I have received `in admin` until now?
3. How many remain?

Using a pivot table i solved my first and second question.
To calculate the value for the `sum of remain` column i tried to use a calculated field but I got wrong results (see below).

[image: Using caclulated field to get the sum of remain]

### Desired result and question

I would like to achieve to get a pivot table like the example table below.

How can create a pivot table where the colum `remain` is the result of `count of po no`-`count of po_in_admin`?

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 1):

One comment linked this youtube tutorial [Learn Excel 2013 - "Subtract in a Pivot Table": Podcast #1655](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhcdLQqJuak) by Bill Jelen and Bill gives these steps

- on the design tab change the report layout of the pivot-table to `tabular form`
- under options click the button `Field Settings` under the tab `Subtotals & Filters` set the radio-button under subtotals to none and click ok
- now select the first column (in your case `count of po no`) - ‘count of po_in_admin’
- under `options` click on `Calculations` click on `Field Items & Set` and pick `calculate elements` enter a column name (for example Delta po no) click the first entry add - click the second entry and hit ok

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no need for a difference column.

Do what you did above:

Right click on one cell with data that you would like to calculate the difference of (note you will deal with the entire row in a minute).

Click insert formula.

Write (insert first header - insert second header).

Change name to your liking.

Press ok

You should then see a new field within your four quadrants ("diff"). Click the info button and change the type from Count to SUM (up on the top). Let me know if that fixes it. The sum will actually calculate the formula associated with the one you just inserted into the pivot table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i change count to sum for 'diff' field but does not work, i check with new sample of 'product, , 'price' ,... It works but when we use count for counting some 'document, .... And we need subtracting it does not work

Comment: @masoud-- Sorry but your comment seems a little disjointed. Can you please clearly write out what is going on.

Comment: @masoud-  It's very hard to fix this problem without seeing a clear view of the four quadrants. Make sure you move the pivot table fields so that they do not cover the data. Remember, with a pivot table, the "values" quadrant will result in a new row. You could always move the Sum Of ... to a new quadrant though.

Comment: For clear view of the four quadrants I edited my question